# Excel Count How Many Assemblies I Can Make From Current Components In stock?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Could someone please give me some assistance on the below?

I have been trying to figure out how I can count how many Assemblies can be built from the current stock levels of its sub-components.

**For Example:-**

- Column A: Sub Component Names
- Column B: Amount Required per Assembly.
- Column C: Amount currently in stock.
- Column D1: Return how many assemblies can be built from the current stock levels of its sub-components?

**Assembly Breakdown (components required):-**

- Component A: Required Qty (1) - Stock Qty (10)
- Component B: Required Qty (2) - Stock Qty (15)
- Component C: Required Qty (1) - Stock Qty (25)

Given this example, I should be able to make 7 assemblies as I don't have enough of component B to build more.

Any help on a formula for this would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

-Grady

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 =MIN(INT(C1:C3/B1:B3))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will create an array of numbers that are the stock available divided by quantity required per.  Then it will find the minimum value of that array.

[image]